# Search specific non-ASCII chars in Unix

Tags: bash, shell, unix

Is it possible to search `ï¿½` set on non-ASCII chars in a file in unix?

I want to search all these characters in bash to replace them with two spaces.

`sed -i 's/[ï¿½]/\ \ /g' filename` worked worked finally

Answer (score 1):

The way to search for those chars will depend on their *encoding* in the file. If the file is in the UTF-8 encoding, you can set the UTF-8 locale and simply match them from the shell. Assuming GNU sed (the default on Linux), the command line will look like this:

```
LANG=C.UTF-8 sed -i 's/[ï¿½]/  /g' filename
```

For this to work, you must be in a UTF-8-compliant shell, so that e.g. `echo 'ï' | wc -c` outputs `3` (two UTF-8 code units plus newline).

Comment: echo 'ï' | wc -c gives me 2 in my shell

Comment: First off, `wc -c` counts *bytes*, not *characters, so you should use `-m` since multibyte characters can consist of, well, multiple bytes ... Also, `echo` ouputs the string *plus* a newline, so 2 is the expected output here. Use `echo -n` to *not* print the newline.

Comment: @Carpetsmoker The answer specifies `wc -c` with the **intention** of counting the bytes, to ascertain that the OP is using a UTF-8 environment/shell. In the future, please be sure to comment before editing an answer you do not understand.

Comment: @MayankJain What is the encoding of the files - how are they created?

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be looking at UTF-8 data using a Latin-1 tool.  Hence, your question is basically ill-defined, but assuming you want to find files containing a UTF-8 replacement character, try something like

```
perl -CSD -nle 'if m/^\x{FFFD}/ { print $ARGV; close() }' files ...
```

Here's what I used to understand your question:

```
$ echo -n 'ï¿½' | iconv -t iso-8859-1 | xxd
0000000: efbf bd
```

Googling for `efbfbd` quickly brought up http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0fffd/index.htm among the top hits.

Note also that U+FFFD is basically an error code.  You should properly *not* find and replace it.  You should find out which previous encoding step failed and produced this, and fix that instead.